# SVN 1.4 Merge, revisions not appearing in log

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

I'm using SVN 1.4.2 and I branched at revision R, merged in the revisions from R-HEAD, and now when I look at the log on the branch, I only see revisions up to R, none between R and HEAD. Is it possible to get this information?

I am using TortoiseSVN 1.6, which is based on SVNClient 1.6.12. I did not have the "Only record the merge (block revisions from getting merged)" box checked. I tried "Inlcude merged revisions", but that apparently runs a mergeinfo which isn't supported until SVN 1.5.

Comment: Why merge revisions from r to head into the branch? branch and trunk would be identical after this unless you do somethong on the branch itself. The commit should be visible in the log of the branch though. You did commit your merge, did you?

Comment: I did make changes to the branch between the branch and merge actions. The commit of the merge is visible, yes, but not the individual revisions from trunk that comprise that merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVN 1.4 doesn't have merge tracking. Therefore, it has no way of knowing the source of a merged into a branch. If it doesn't know where a merge came from, it can't know where to get the log messages for that merge.

The only real solution is to upgrade your server to 1.5 or higher.

If you want logs from previous branches to appear, you'll need to recreate the branch and recommit the revisions.

Comment: +1 for upgrade. It's the best solution - its easy and you get good features. Also 1.4 will soon be as (un)supported as 1.3 (ie not at all)

Comment: I was thinking that when I performed the merge, SVN would have been intelligent enough to merge the list of revisions into my working copy as well. But apparently it doesn't bother (see my answer).

Comment: Although if we were to upgrade and do the merge, the revision history would not follow, would it?

Comment: The revision history won't become part of the merge, if that's what you mean. But using TortoiseSVN's "Include merged revisions" checkbox will interlace the logs from merged revisions. However, that won't work for anything in the repository prior to the server upgrade.

Comment: Thanks Dingo, just to double check, if I upgrade, I have to do the merge over again, correct? If so, please incorporate into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that this is actually a feature.

Branches are supposed to be quick offshoots to build up some functionality without mucking up trunk. The whole merge, together, should only comprise one real change of trunk. The little incremental steps aren't supposed to be significant with regards to the trunk development.

In our case, a branch was made and developed for over a year. Ideally we'd have the history to look over, but our branching methodology violated the "correct" way to do things, and we will consequently lose history. There ARE ways to hack around this, but in our case fixing one hack with another hack is worse than losing some history and learning our lesson.

If anyone has a way to hack this together, please do share!

Thanks